# ULN2803A PWM LED High Watt/Ampere

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, led, transistors, raspberry-pi

Reading the [ULN2803A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2803a.pdf) datasheet, especially the part "**[Figure 13. ULN2803A as Inductive Load Driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgbBT.gif)**" and after [various](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/172543/76228) [fails](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/170380/76228) to properly drive 12v RGB led strips, as i can't find the proper mosfets. i was thinking to get more of those ULN2803 and use them like a "mosfet".

> 500-mA-Rated Collector Current
>
> Total substrate-terminal current –2.5 A

This means if i connect one pin of my 3.3v or 5v microcontroller to all 8 intputs , and all 8 outputs (gnd) to the leds , basically solder them all together, i get a max of 12v@2.5A=30W on one ULN2803A.

Using PWM on 3x ULN2803A, doing the same as above, would allow me to get 12v@7.5A=90W Led strip to run properly.

**Would i be able to properly power the 2x [5m led strip](http://www.alphaelettronica.com/jo350rgb-a.html) or less, assuming i have 7.5A@12v=90W and the strip consumes 7.2W/m*10m=72W, without problems (except the obious voltage drop on a 10m strip)?**

Said that, if it's correct, the ULN2803A is for 3.3v & 5v and so has already all the protection and logic stuff inside, so i don't need any resistors, diodes, transistors or whatever to protect my Microcontroller?

Basically i just need to connect the Arduino(5v) OR Raspberry (3.3v) signal pins to the ULN2803A inputs, the GND of the led strip to the outputs and the ground to the microcontroller and 12v powersupply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDbnYN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

note.: i use a industrial 12v 10A/5A(with a shorter led strip) power supply if everything is clear

btw if i connect the Raspberry that has very low output (20-40mA) on **one single 3.3v PIN** 
 how much current sucks **each ULN2803 input**?

> II(on) Input current VI = 3.85 V, See Figure 6 0.93 1.35 mA

So if max is 1.35mA, let's say 1.5mA*8inputs=**12mA** there are no problems to power them all with just one pin???

And regarding the length of the strip this would also allow me to easely gie power at every 1-2 or 3m to have a nice stable 12v....And so i would have no voltage drop.

What about PWM on 8in and 8out... it could create some errors on the linearity of the PWM signal???

**"No, your totally wrong, the reaspberry has not enough mA to power all 8 inputs with one PIN"** or **"Yes, you can handle 7.5A at 12v and the Raspberry is safe"** would be enough as answer.

I'm not a electronical enginer. So sorry for my low knowledge about electronics.

**Are my assumptions correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only answer part of your questions.

1) I simply don't know how much current a Raspberry pin will put out, and Broadcom is very short on information. I recommend this: buy one 2803, hook it up with all the inputs tied together but no load, and measure the voltage at the inputs.

2) I can guarantee that with all the inputs tied together, you will draw less than 12 mA with an input of 3.3 volts. How can I say this? The spec you listed gives an input of 3.85 volts, not 3.3 volts. Lower voltage will give you lower current. But measure it. If the Raspberry cannot provide close to 3.3 volts when driving all 8 inputs, you may have extra problems with point 3.

3) Yes, you can pull 2.5 amps with one chip. I don't recommend it, but you can do it. If you do, you MUST provide a decent heat sink for the 2803. If you just use a bare IC you will burn it out. You should assume something like 1.3 volts across the 2803, and at 2.5 amps, your total power will be about 3.3 watts. The thermal resistance to ambient for this chip (section 7.4 in the data sheet) is 74 degrees per watt, so the heart of the chip will reach (3.3 x 74) + 20 degrees, or about 260 degrees C. Per the data sheet, the maximum is 125 C.

If your input voltage is low, the outputs will not turn on as hard, and the voltage drop across the outputs may be greater. In that case, the power dissipation of the chip will be higher, and you will need a bigger heat sink. But this is something that you will need to experiment with to find out. I suspect you'll be OK, but I'm not giving any guarantees.

Comment: 1. From various sources a Raspberry pi can output 16mA@3.3v max per pin and a total of 50mA. So using only one 3 pin's theoretically would allow me to stay in the limits?

Comment: 2.Good so i even consume less on the raspberry pi side and can use more pins.

Comment: 3.You should assume something like 1.3 volts across the 2803? Are there heatsinks for those dip IC's? btw i'm naturally not using all the 2.5A per chip but around 1.5A-2.0A would be nice. without heatsinks. now if i get how you get those 3.3W i can calculate myself how hot i get it with 2A

Comment: Input voltage is should be 3.3v using Pulse with modulation.+1 thx

Comment: @cocco 1. With a 3.3 volt line, you may well be able to source 16 mA, but I guarantee that voltage will be somewhat less than 3.3 volts. Exactly how much, I don't know, and the data sheets I've found are not silent on the subject. You'll have to experiment.

Comment: @cocco 2. Somewhat less. I don't know exactly how much, so you'll need to test to find out.

Comment: @cocco 3. Yes. Look at the data sheet Typical Characteristics section 7.7. There are heatsinks quite cheap. Google "dip heatsink". You want "thermal resistance" as low as you can get. Look at section 7.4. You want junction to case (top) then add the thermal resistance of the heatsink. Use the total.

Comment: 7.7 Figure 1 says i need around 2v to get the 500mA, Figure 2 says i need 2.5 volt to get 800mA if in paralell. right? And oi totally don't understand what Figure 3. Output Current vs Input Current
 means. I need around 110mA from microcontroller to output 400mA with 8v?

Comment: but that would be mean that noone should be able to run a uln2803 with a microcontroller

Comment: @cocco - in all 3 cases, input current is in microamps.

Comment: uA? μA=micro mA=milli?? http://www.ti.com/ods/images/SLRS049G/tc3_slrs023.gif confused.

Comment: @cocco - As well you might be. In figures 1 and 2, the "micro" prefix is missing on the curves, and on figure 3 it's just wrong. Micro, not milli.

Comment: So i made this calculation again with only .5A * 1.3v = .65W * 74deg/W + 20deg = 68.1 degCelsius by using only one pin? to output 1A i would already reach the 120deg Limit?? this means i already need a big heatsink as soon i want to use 2 pins fully, and with 2A i need to dissipate 200W?? where do i need to measure these 1.3v voltage? on the connected inputs? signal pin to uln2803 input? "hook it up with all the inputs tied together but no load, and measure the voltage at the inputs"

Comment: Voltage is load pin to ground. And yes, the chip will get hot, although this is sort of a worst case analysis. And 1 amp will give (1 x 74) + 20, or 94 degrees. Depending on exactly how much input drive your Arduino can produce, you might get as low as 1 volt, so the temperature would be less. Time to stop thinking. Go let out some magic smoke, then start another question with what went wrong.

Comment: some days ago i tested the uln and i checked continuosly for the heat emmitted... i connected 8x 10cm led strips with 3 leds each the 5630 each strip consumed around 80mA(milliampere) after some testing i turned on constantly 3 strips and measured the total consumption it was around 230mA.doing the math that would mean it should touch (with room temp 22*C) around 44.1*C. but i touched it after a while... and for me there wasn't 44deg celssius

Comment: lol no magic smoke i love all my new ic's, resistors and transistors!!!!! btw on your perfect answer http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/172553/76228 wich is working perfectly on arduino ... but it has not enough power to turn on the green transistor with raspberry... you think i should lower that resistor from 1kohm maybe to 900ohm-800ohm that goes from raspberry to to the first transistor?

Comment: ah the 1.3 volt are refered to the VCE(sat) Collector-emitter saturation voltage. if correct that means you can run this IC at 800mA if you plan to not turn on every single output continuosly as it reaches 84°C on a continuos load of 800mA and already that is very hot. got it. and if you output more than 100mA per pint the VCE starts to get unstable and your temperature increases exponentially!

Comment: Looking at the second graph, considering my first guess of 2.5A / 8 pin = 312mA each pin. Only by adding the second pin and so needing at least 624mA the VCE would be already at 1.5v and so touch the 131°C.

Comment: with a increment in the VCE of 1.2 per pin using 310mA i would end up at 3.5v VCE , so at around 600-700°C if i let 2.5A pass trough the ULN2803A