# Led driver circuit 3.3v & 5v

Tags: led, transistors, resistors

Not long time ago, as i couldn't find a proper Mosfet to drive a high wattage led strip ( 5050,5630), i asked how to create a circuit that allows me to turn on properly the mosfets i already own. irf510,irf520 and the RFP70N06.
[Led Driver/Controller for 3.3v & 5v circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/172543/76228)
i got it working an before i hooked it up to my microcontrollers i tested it with some 3v batteries(CR2032) leaving out the R1 resistor. it worked. then i put 3 1k resistors there. And used it with an arduino. And it worked. Not that i tested it much but everything was fine. Now i just finished to setup a new microcontroller, Raspberrry PI... so the difference is the 3.3v vs 5v of the arduino.

**With the Raspberry Pi 3.3v i'm not able to turn on the green part of the led strip.**

Now, the answer is prolly ... put a smaller resistor in R1.(wich one?)

But i want to understand.

1. The leds, red needs less voltage(2.1), the green needs more(3.1). but isn't the blue the one that normally needs more voltage(3.2)?
   could this be a problem?
2. As i'm just driving a transistor with a Raspberry pin the above has not much sense. if i'm able to turn on red and blue i should aslo be able to turn on green.
   where should i measure whats wrong?(i have a multimeter, no oscill..).
3. Maybe the raspberry pi's pin's don't all output the same voltage. Would that be normal?
4. if it's possible i want to be able to control this circuit with both logics 3.3v and 5v...  so if i need 2 different R1's i could desolder the 1k ones and create a custom smaller connection circuit to use with each logic. in that case what resistors should i use? or even better **how can i calculate myself what resistors i need to drive it properly looking at the datasheet?**
   [RFP70N06](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/RF/RFP70N06.pdf),  [2N3904](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/2N3904.pdf)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo3ctB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Note: The above schematics is for one channel there are 3 !!! red,green,blue.**

Comment: Are you still using the 12V supply? LED data sheet?

Comment: i'm using a "12v @ 6A Ac/Dc Adapter Led Driver"

Comment: You shouldn't have to change R1 - are you sure green isn't broken?

Comment: i measured it and it out puts exactly 12.06v

Comment: with arduino it works

Comment: i also changed pin ... i think so question 3 ... is useless..

Comment: the problem is in the circuit, maybe i'm at the limit with 3.3v and 1k resistor?

Comment: http://www.alphaelettronica.com/jo350rgb-a.html led no datasheet... but it's the 5050 rgb

Comment: i tested with arduino it worked, then i tested with raspberry green doesn't work, then i tested with arduino again it worked, then i tested with raspberry no green. then i switched the blue pin with the green one, green didn't work.

Comment: In an alternate universe this probably makes sense but, here on earth.....

Comment: now i measured the resistors..  they are all 995-1k

Comment: i know it's strange

Comment: Measure voltages at the base of each transistor and compare the values. At least in the green array, one must be off.

Comment: Just as a side note here: You say you put 3V from batteries on the transistors without a resistor: Bad idea. You may have already inadvertently damaged some transistors. For proper debugging you should try a few new transistors and _never_ use them without a resistor. In a switching set up the resistor prevents the transistor from pulling too much base current. Too much base current = bad. These resistors are already low, so they should work for anything as low as 1.8V even.

Comment: CR2032 don't they already have very low mA output. btw i really just touched and removed... also testing right now... arduino works... raspberry no... like above the green does not turn on... only the green even if i switch pins.

Comment: so you think the first green transistor is damadged?? but why does the arduino work?

Comment: https://youtu.be/GzEt3UCjJcg Arduino working perfectly, Raspberry pi is set to rgb(0,255,0) but nothing(code works, if i put the red or blue to power the green leds i have same results. green leds don't turn on) https://youtu.be/o2walMCefKg

Comment: Same circuit.... the only difference is the 3.3v vs 5v.... are you 100% shure that i'm not at the limit with 1k ohm resistor?

Comment: http://led.linear1.org/1led.wiz?VS=3.3;VF=1.8;ID=2 .... so with a 820ohm resistor i'm able to output 2mA at 1.8v ... how much mA does the 2n3904 need to saturate? i'm using 1k ohm ... so i output less than 2mA to the 2n3904... right^?

Comment: & i repeat .. @ 5v everything works. strange.. "In an alternate universe this probably makes sense but, here on earth" ... @Andy aka yep

Comment: CR2032 should output around 3v@20mA.... could that break a 2n3904??

Comment: @Asmyldof the cr2032 should output only max 20mA. Can the 2n3904 handle 20mA at the base?

Comment: @cocco CR2032 is less of a risk than a penlite, that's for certain and it makes it a lot less likely, I didn't gather that from your earlier comment, but you should still _never_ rely on internal resistances doing their job for you, because a mistake is easy to make. Also with the advent of CR2032 powered pocket lights I can imagine companies trying to increase the current capability (at the cost of long term storage, maybe). But that might still have been okay.

Comment: So... can a 2n3904 handle 20mA at the base? but most of all if we do rhe math based on the 1,8v @3.3v with a 1k resistor the mA output is under 2mA ... is that enough? i don't think they gonna change the output of the cr2032 especially now that they use it to directly drive leds and that the 20mA is a standard for the cr2032.

Comment: appart from not complete datasheets, theories of broken parts and that a 1k resitor is always a good choice can't someone show some math how to calculate the proper resistor? wich is actually what i hope to get as answer.

Comment: like i said, if the minimum is 1,8v at any positive number of ampere, applying the same calculation that is used to feed a led we are around 0mA . with 5v around 10mA . this with a 1k resistor. as not every electronical part is perfect i assume a 700-800ohm resistor would make a difference. but i'm not an electronical engineer. i'm just trying to understand. For now noone disagreed with that theory. i hope someone does and explains me why.

Answer (score 2):

There is a few possible scenarios. There are three parts here. The input (ie the arduino, rpi, or battery), the transistor circuit, and the output (the led channel). If you switch them around, you should be able to figure which one is the problem.

If Rpi + Green Transistor Circuit + Green led channel doesn't work, first try switching the led channel. Still don't work? Switch the transistor circuit for the blue one with the blue led channel (same rpi pin). If that works, put the blue transistor circuit with the green led channel.

If that doesn't work, then try a different RPI pin with the blue transistor circuit and the green leds.

That should eliminate any hardware issue. If it doesn't work, then it's likely software based. If the RPI pin isn't set to the right current level, or its the wrong pin, it won't work. Remember the rpi is limited to 16mA max, or less, based on setting. That said,  1k resistor means just 2.6mA at the base of the initial transistor.

Comment: with 5v everything works, the various 3.3v pins work on every channel appart from the green one. so the problem is 100% the first "green" transistor. how do you get 2.6mA?

Comment: As the "green" transistor works with 5v & 1k resistor, i think it just needs some more juice from the rpi to work and that at this point the "green" 2n3904 has a problem. could it be that it is partially damadged and so needs more mA to switch?

Comment: So if you put the blue led channel on the green circuit, it works? Have you checked for bad solder joints? The 2.6mA is (V - Vbe) / R. In this case, 3.3v - 0.7v (typical) / 1000 ohms.

Comment: so basically i don't even saturate properly the transistor with 1000k ohm?? No bad soldering(it works with arduino) if i put the green output pin from raspberry at the blue transistor i can control properly the blue leds with the green values.. the blue(rpi) pin is not able to turn on the green(transistor) leds.

Comment: No, a 1 Mega ohm resistor won't saturate it. A 1k ohm with a Ice of 12mA would be fine, it's acting as a switch not a current amplifier. So if you can put the coin cell 3V battery at the green transistor base with a 700 or so resistor, does it turn on? If not, replace the circuit. All those parts are a dime or so. Are you sure you have a 2n3904 there? Cause I can tell you I've mixed transistors up before.

Comment: lol i meant 1k ohm

Comment: so i just touched the 3v battery and it turns on but not saturated. dimmed. with the 1k resistor.

Comment: and now this is really strange. because why wouldn't the raspberry be able to turn on only the green part using pwm.even if i switch pin. and the 3v battery is able to turn it on?'

Comment: ah and yeah all 2n3904 , plus i manually cut between the solder points... even if everything looked correct. just to be shure.

Comment: So replace the circuit with new parts.

Comment: maybe it's the pwm frequency?

Comment: Double check the library settings

Comment: tomorrow i try to replace the part even if i don't understand how it is possible that it works with an arduino but not with a rpi, thank you for your help.